# Is there a way include a firefox extension popup in the Content-Security-Policy of my website?

Tags: firefox-addon, content-security-policy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I want to embed an iframe in the popup of a firefox extension but I get "*Firefox Can’t Open This Page - To protect your security, [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) will not allow Firefox to display the page if another site has embedded it.*" and it is because the site example.com has configured the  `Content-Security-Policy` with `frame-ancestors 'self'`. I can change it to `frame-ancestors *` but I would like something less broad.

Comment: Looks like the specification [allows only web schemes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) so you can't add an extension.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what origin your popup window has (what is specified in `<iframe src=` or in `<iframe srcdoc=`)
Some origins is a subject of CSP regulation, the other is not. For example, vendor's schemes like `moz-extension:` / `chrome:` should bypass the CSP.

Also the 'self' token can be very insidious:

```
,----------------- parent HTTP://example.com --------------------,
|                                                                |
|  * Host-source is HTTP://example.com with the HTTP: scheme     |
|                                                                |
|  <iframe src='HTTPS://example.com'>                            |
|   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'              |
|                                                                |
|    * 'self' would be substituted by HTTPS://example.com, it    |
|     means that you actually have the header:                   |
|   Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors HTTPS://example.com |
|     therefore it will block embedding into parent with         |
|     HTTP://example.com because of schemes mismatch             |
|     (HTTP: !== HTTPS:)                                         |
|                                                                |
|  <iframe>                                                      |
|________________________________________________________________|
```

But the opposite situation (parent with HTTPS: and iframe with HTTP:) will not cause problems in CSP3 browsers (but will cause in CSP2 ones).

Answer (score 0):

In case of IIS you need to change X-FRAME-OPTIONS header from "Deny" to "SAME-ORIGIN" or add the X-FRAME-OPTIONS if it does not exist. To do that:

- Open IIS Manager and on the left hand tree, left click the site you would like to manage.
- Doubleclick the “HTTP Response Headers” icon.
- Right click the header list and select “Add”
- For the “name” write “X-FRAME-OPTIONS” and for the value write in your desired option e.g. “SAME-ORIGIN”.